# Ignoring a single slicer selection?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a single-selection slicer controlling a donut visual. It has 4 options, A, B, C, & D. I want that when "A" is selected, the visual should ignore the slicer and show all data. On other selections, it should act as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly.

You can use the Edit Interaction option to ignore filter on a particular view.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to ignore the whole filter, just a single selection available in the filter.